# Compare string without calling function in assembly?

Tags: assembly, nasm

Say I have two strings, I want to compare the string but don't want to call another function for `true` or `false`:

```
mov rsi, 0x4141414141414141
mov rdi, 0x6161616161616161
cmp rsi, rdi
// if true do here
// otherwise do here
// jmp back_up_to_cmp rsi, rdi
```

The problem I have is that, I cannot call a function for either true or false. So, is there anyway to achieve my expectation?

Comment: Have you tried a conditional jump?

Comment: @fuz well `jmp` have to be `jmp to_function` which is what I don't want.

Comment: No, you can `jne` to a label within the current function.  Look at how compilers implement `if`.  See the comments on [comparing string without using jmp in assembly?](//stackoverflow.com/q/60255130) which has a similar point of confusion.

Comment: @Noobx I think I don't really understand the restrictions you have.  I am not really interested in answering such a question as the list of restrictions tends to suddenly have new entries once I wrote an answer.

Comment: @fuz I am trying to study shellcode development, that is why I cannot get the opcode of functions. So either I have to specify function address directly in cpu or execute the code within the same function.

Comment: @noobx What is the “opcode of functions?”  Please try to use correct terms for the things you are talking about.  Note that jumps (both conditional and unconditional ones) have their targets encoded relative to the instruction pointer, so there is no problem jumping to a different section of your shellcode even if the actual address is unknown; only the distance needs to be known.

Comment: Those aren't *strings* in the sense we use that term.

Comment: **You can use relative branches in shellcode; they're position-independent**.  Exact duplicate of [comparing string without using jmp in assembly?](//stackoverflow.com/q/60255130) (but that only has comments for answers)

Comment: @fuz, So, how do I jump back to `cmp` location if the condition is e.g true? looked at the disassembly of my code, and `cmp` is located `0x0000555555555168` but obviously, it would be in a different location if executed next time.

Comment: @Noobx Just use another jump.  Again: the jump is relative, so you can just jump there, regardless of where your code is loaded.

Comment: @fuz can you give an example in assembly code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by @fuz, I could use relative jump to achieve what I wanted:

working complete code:

```
SECTION .text
global main

main:
mov rax, 1
mov rsi, 0x203e7475706e49
push rsi
mov rsi, rsp
mov rdx, 7
syscall

mov rax, 0
mov rdi, 0
mov rsi, rsp
mov rdx, 256
syscall

mov rax, 1
mov rsi, rsp

xor rdx, rdx
cmp byte [rsi + rdx], 0x0a
jz 0xc
inc rdx
jmp -0xe

syscall

mov rax, 60
syscall
```

I looked at the location in which my `cmp` was located at, calculated the difference and used the `jmp` to jump to that location:

```
0x0000000000001130 <+0>:     mov    $0x1,%eax
0x0000000000001135 <+5>:     movabs $0x203e7475706e49,%rsi
0x000000000000113f <+15>:    push   %rsi
0x0000000000001140 <+16>:    mov    %rsp,%rsi
0x0000000000001143 <+19>:    mov    $0x7,%edx
0x0000000000001148 <+24>:    syscall 
0x000000000000114a <+26>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
0x000000000000114f <+31>:    mov    $0x0,%edi
0x0000000000001154 <+36>:    mov    %rsp,%rsi
0x0000000000001157 <+39>:    mov    $0x100,%edx
0x000000000000115c <+44>:    syscall 
0x000000000000115e <+46>:    mov    $0x1,%eax
0x0000000000001163 <+51>:    mov    %rsp,%rsi
0x0000000000001166 <+54>:    xor    %rdx,%rdx
0x0000000000001169 <+57>:    cmpb   $0xa,(%rsi,%rdx,1)
0x000000000000116d <+61>:    je     0x117b <main+75>
0x0000000000001173 <+67>:    inc    %rdx
0x0000000000001176 <+70>:    jmpq   0x1169 <main+57>
0x000000000000117b <+75>:    syscall 
0x000000000000117d <+77>:    mov    $0x3c,%eax
0x0000000000001182 <+82>:    syscall 
0x0000000000001184 <+84>:    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
0x000000000000118e <+94>:    xchg   %ax,%ax
```

So no more functions :) Thank you @fuz

Comment: You can simply use labels.  There's no need to manually compute those addresses.

Comment: @fuz, I am sorry kinda noob with assembly, So, do labels have opcode? and can it be used inside shellcodes?

Comment: A label is just a name for a memory location.  Labels do not generate any code, they are just a convenience thing.